# BlueSnap Payment API: How can I validate a card without charging it?

Tags: payment-gateway, bluesnap

I am integrating with BlueSnap using the Payment API and want to just validate the card without charging any amount. Does BlueSnap provide such a capability?

Answer (score 2):

It seems they allow you to do a zero sum authorization, which counts as a card account validation request: http://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/auth-only

> If you wish to check the validity of a card without authorizing any charge amount, simply enter **0** as the value for the `amount` property in this request.

But be aware that this validation does not necessarily tell you whether you are free to use the card without the security code CVC (for card-on-file transactions for example). This might need additional checks depending on the BlueSnap implementation.